# Relationship Between Variables Both Growing/Decreasing, not Proportional

Tags: functions, terminology

So proportional is when the variables are equal to one another when multiplied by a constant.

What is the term for something like weak proportionality that when one variable increases the other will as well, but not necessarily in a linear fashion? This would include all linear and odd polynomial relationships and much more.

Example: x=5y is a linear relationship, but x=2y^3 isn't. Nonetheless these functions are both ______ because when x increases in either, y will also.

Thanks!

Comment: In Statistics, positively correlated.

Comment: One can say that one variable is a function of the other, and specify that this function is strictly increasing.

Comment: One sometimes says that one variable "moves with" the other